# add a link on a div displayed on input's focus

Tags: html, css

I show a tooltip when an input gains focus. This tooltip is a span: hidden, but shown (via CSS) when input has focus.

```css
input + .k-comments {
      display: none;
      max-width: 25em;
      color: #FFF;
      background: #283135;
      padding: 0.3rem;
      margin-top: 0.3rem;
      animation: appearance 2s forwards;
    }

    input:focus + .k-comments {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<input id="myid" type="text"/>
<span class="k-comments">foo <a href="www.google.com">a link</a></span>
```

If I click on the tooltip (or everywhere else), it disappears: ok.
The problem: my tooltip contains text and a link -> I can't click on the link because the tooltip disappears first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the best solution but at least it makes the link clickable:

```
input:focus + .k-comments,
.k-comments:active {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Remember to accept the answer @JonathanLermitage

Comment: Damned, I tested on Chrome and Firefox only. It doesn't work on IE11.

Comment: finally, IE11 needs to set "display:block" on ".k-comments:hover" too :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
input + .k-comments {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 25em;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #283135;
  padding: 0.3rem;
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}

input:focus + .k-comments {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: none;
}
```

My solution :add a hidden transition to the comment.